# Can I power my MacBook Pro 2023 with MacBook Air 30W adapter?

Tags: charger, macbook

Can I power my MacBook Pro 2023 with MacBook Air 30W adapter? Any potential for damage? I believe the answer is no, but seeking some second opinions.

Answer (score 1):

It will communicate and charge at its max charger capacity.

**BUT** it may not match the rate the Pro 23 is using power so the battery will end up discharged, however it will last langer than no charging at all. Just depends what software etc you are running ie how hard you run the processor.

Comment: Thanks makes sense.